# Why does valgrind give me an error with malloc?

Tags: c

I am new to valgrind and am trying to figure out why it is throwing me the following error:

```
==9976== Invalid write of size 1

==9976==    at 0x4C32E0D: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9976==    by 0x109907: duplicate (parse.c:22)

==9976==    by 0x1099AB: parse (parse.c:84)

==9976==    by 0x108E8E: load_employees (emp.c:245)

==9976==    by 0x108B62: main (rpt.c:28)

==9976==  Address 0x522fe59 is 0 bytes after a block of size 9 alloc'd

==9976==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)

==9976==    by 0x1098F0: duplicate (parse.c:20)

==9976==    by 0x1099AB: parse (parse.c:84)

==9976==    by 0x108E8E: load_employees (emp.c:245)

==9976==    by 0x108B62: main (rpt.c:28)
```

My function:

```
static char *duplicate( const char *str ) {
    int len = sizeof( str );
    char *buf = (char *) malloc( (len + 1)* sizeof(*buf));

    strcpy( buf, str );
    return( buf );
}
```

The parse.c line 22 is the "return( buf );"

Comment: Your `duplicate` function would crash when `malloc` fails.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof( str )` is either 4 or 8 on most modern architectures (on yours, it appears to be 8, given the valgrind output indicates 9 bytes were allocated), no matter how many characters were in the string it pointed to. `sizeof` is going to tell you the size needed to store the pointer itself, not the length of the string it points to.

Instead, use:

```
size_t len = strlen(str);
```

to compute the length of the `NUL`-terminated string you were passed.

BTW, many systems provide [strdup](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strndup.3.html), which does exactly what your `duplicate` function should do.

Comment: Note: On a lot of systems, you could just replace this function [with `strdup`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) which has behavior identical to your intended behavior.